# Marking face and eyes on image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, face-detection, ios5

I am working on a app that detects face  and marks eyes and mouth on image.I have detected the face ,eyes and mouth using CIDetector but the position of eyes and face that it returns is with respect to original image not according to the view of imageview on which i have to mark faces and eyes i.e for example i have a image of 720 *720 the position of face and eyes that it retuns is with respect to size of 720 *720.But the problem is ..i have to show eyes and face annotated on a image view of size 320 * 320. please advice me how can i map the postion of face returned by CIdetector to position of face on image view.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by considering the imageview size to image size **ratio**.
Following is something really simple and could be used to solve your problem.

```
//'returnedPoint' is the position of eye returned by CIDetector

CGFloat ratio = 320/ 720.0;
//It is like, CGFloat ratio = yourImageView.frame.size.width/ yourImage.size.width;
CGPoint pointOnImageView = CGPointMake((ratio * returnedPoint.x), (ratio * returnedPoint.y));
```